# Check in master page if an element is created dynamically or not in a content page

Tags: javascript

I need to check from master page if an radio button group is created on runtime using javascript in the content page based on certain conditions, if created I wanted to know what value is selected by user. Is there a way to do this.

I am trying to do it like below

```
    function computeTotal()
    {
        outboundTotal = selectedTotal("Outbound");
        inboundTotal = selectedTotal("Inbound");
        total = outboundTotal + inboundTotal;
    }

function selectedTotal(candidateName) {

  if(Check if candidatename is created or not in the content page from 
   master page)
  {
       if created which radio button is selected by user
    {}
  }

}
```

Comment: Is there a class (css) attached to these radio buttons that appear dynamically. Would be helpful if you provide more details about the HTML itself. what do you mean by master page?

Comment: btw the answer is yes -> you can achieve what you are intending to. You can find those radio buttons on the page by looking for them using what is called as `selectors` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) in javascript or by their id etc.

Comment: I am trying to create a radio button group within a div class in the content page. There can be 2 sets of groups thats why I am trying to pass the group name. This groups are created if data is there else nothing. If the group exists I want to determine which radio button in the group was selected by the user

Comment: ^^ does not answer the question ->  I thought you said you wanted to know which radio button is selected -> need a bit more clarity. My question was is there a css class attached to these radio buttons ?

Comment: Yes a css class is assosiated. There can be 2 groups that uses same class but different radio button names thats why I am trying to pass the group name. This groups are created if data is there else nothing. If the group exists I want to determine which radio button in the group was selected by the user